# Google Calendar API add event not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-python-client

I am new to coding and I am creating a project that requires the use of Google Calendar API(basically I am making a voice assistant)

Python Version = 3.9 64 bit
windows = windows 10 64 bit

now I want to do 2 tasks with the API

1. to get already created events(this function is working fine.)
2. to create new events

I have made a function that would take a string(our query) and then provide us a string which has a structure like this: `'2021-03-15T10:30:00+5:30'`

This function is working fine as I have tested it many times.

but my other function which creates the events is giving an output like this

```
<bound method HttpRequest.execute of <googleapiclient.http.HttpRequest object at 0x0000011B0F21F280>>
```

I don't know why this is happening but this could be caused by two function(most probably) those are

1. the google authentication function

```
def authenticate_google(scopes):
    """
    authenticates google(if already authenticated, uses pickle) will return service which contains the calendar
    :return:
    """
    # If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
    SCOPES = scopes

    creds = None
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file('client_secret.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=creds)

    return service
```

I don't know why this is not working for creating events as it is working for getting events function

2)the create events function

```
def create_events(start, end, content, service):
    EVENT = {'summary': content,
             'start': {'dateTime': start},
             'end': {'dateTime': end}}
    service = service
    ce = service.events().insert(calendarId='primary',
                                 sendNotifications=True,
                                 body=EVENT).execute
    print(ce)
```

this function should create the event but I don't know why no event is created when I am running it it just gives the same output and then stops.

[Here](https://github.com/Dynocoder/test/blob/main/main.py) is the full code if you wanna take a look(to save your time I should tell you that all the other functions except these are working, so you might not need to check that)

Comment: I tried to replicate your code and I was able to create an event. Have you tried deleting the token.pickle and rerun the code again? Also, the hour in the timezone of your dateTime should have double digits. Example: `2021-03-15T10:30:00+05:30`

Comment: You are not calling `execute`. It should be `.execute()`. Also, I'd suggest using [gcsa](https://github.com/kuzmoyev/google-calendar-simple-api)

Comment: Firstly I am so sorry that I was not able to reply back(I had a test this week) apart from that thanks @NikkoJ. for pointing that out I added a zero to the GMT_OFF. thanks for pointing out such a silly mistake after that it started working

Comment: Also, thank you @YevhenKuzmovych I added the two brackets i.e `.execute` to `.execute()` and It worked. Also thanks for recommending the gcsa. I just wanted to know that my project is already getting a bit system heavy will adding a whole new library make it heavier?

Comment: The library is less than 200 kb :) But I don't recommend switching to it if you have a lot of stuff implemented already. It just simplifies the work with google calendar, like reading credentials, setting timezones, etc.